# How big can be the images in the drawable folders?

Tags: android

How big can be the images in the drawable folders? I've searched in net but I couldn't find any precise answer. Please help

Comment: dont think there s a limit

Comment: I thought so.. but my professor asked me to add such information in my diploma work 8(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so!
Anyways it depends on the device used (SD Card). Larger image can effect the size of app too. So may be you have to look for what max size an Android app can have.

The answer still is, Device Dependent!
If you try to download (install) app with larger size you may get a failure:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/18cbb2404778618e?pli=1) is a thread describing this issue.

Comment: Not just this but I've had problem with out of memory exceptions when users dynamically load in image resources from the web for example and I have to try and capture these and dynamically resize the images to managable sizes.

Comment: still Device Dependent! @DeliveryNinja you are talking about runtime loading which is related to available RAM, again different devices have different amount of RAM available. There is not any science behind the scenes :)